# Android - Unable to set background image but visible in designer

Tags: android, image, background

I'm a bit of a Android noob, as of today.

I have tried setting a picture to the background as follows;

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="C:\Users\Jacob\Downloads\xmas.jpg"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
```

But when i build it comes up with;

'Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'background' with value 'C:\Users\Jacob\Downloads\xmas.jpg').    activity_main.xml   /FirstAndroidApp/res/layout line 1  Android AAPT Problem'

When i go in to the designer it shows the background as i would like it, but just comes up with an error.

Am I not allowed to set a background in this way? or am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In android you should not set background like this. Search a little and you can get your answer.

1. Put your image xmas.jpg in **res/drawable** folder.
2. Change `android:background="C:\Users\Jacob\Downloads\xmas.jpg"` to `android:background="@drawable/xmas"`

In android **.png** is more recommended to use and while using like as i said above no need to give extension like .png or .jpg..

This will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

You have to copy the picture into your `drawable` folder then reference it like so:

```
android:background="@drawable/xmas"
```

Answer (score 1):

to get work it you will need to copy your image in `<Your_Project>/res/drawable` folder and then set `RelativeLayout` background as :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/xmas"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
```

and for more information for adding images in your project see

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html